# Buying an app on one device; rating from another

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Is there some restriction on which device you can rate from?  I like to browse the iOS app store via iTunes from my MacBook, so I often stage apps there for download on the next sync with my iPhone. I just tried to rate a so-installed app from my iPhone and (after typing in and submitting  a review) it said that I need to own the app before I can review it. Is there some sort of synchronization that I have set inappropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you buy the same app using the same iTunes account from different iOS devices, you can rate the app from any of the devices. Synchronization is done between the device you rated the app and Apple's iTunes App Store.

Comment: I definitely bought it with the same account (I only have one) and it shows "installed" when I look at the app in the app store on my iPhone.  I was able to (just now) submit a review of the app using iTunes on my MacBook.

Comment: I just noticed that, although the version numbers are the same (4.58), there are differing dates for the app between the iPhone's app store information ("Post Date December 21 2011") and the iTunes iOS app store information ("Released: Dec 22, 2011").  Here's the app in question: [http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/columbus-library-mobile/id490359413?mt=8]

Comment: The app's Version number is used to compare the app (on your device) and the app at the AppStore. AFAIK, the release date indicates the date the app is available at the AppStore and isn't used to compare app's version.

Comment: I just checked again-- now I'm able to use the app store on my iPhone to edit the review that I submitted via the iTunes iOS app store.  I'm going to chalk this up to some sort of lag in synchronization between the two stores (in this case, something on the order of 10 hours).

Comment: A suggestion that may help if both your iOS devices are on iOS 5.0 or newer as it's now possible for devices to download content without requiring a Mac with iTunes. I've set my iPhone and iPad (both running iOS 5.0.1) to automatically download which is effectively syncing. To do this, launch Settings app. Navigate to Store then under "Automatic Downloads" toggle any button (Music, Apps, Books) that you want. If your data plan has quota, you may want to turn off the "Use Cellular Data" to use only your WiFi. Enjoy your device.

Comment: I have that enabled but it never seems to happen.  I'm wondering now if my renaming of mt iTunes account (quite some time ago--well before I had my iPhone) has something to do with the misbehavior I'm seeing.

Comment: There is still something flakey with the iOS App Store-- I went back to edit the review (via my iPhone) that I'd created on my iPhone for this one app.  I clicked on "submit a review" and it put me in an edit dialog populated with the previous review I'd submitted.  I made edits and then submitted it.  My update was rejected with the message "you must own this app to write a Customer Review".